# Understanding: React state update timing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm going to assume here that my problem lies within the async nature of how React states work (at least I hope that's a correct statement). I have an app where I have created an UI in which there are 4 buttons with values in them and an "OK" button. The user tries to choose the largest value by clicking the corresponding value button and then clicking "OK" to confirm their choice.

When, why and how does React update my `this.setState({ value: this.state.chosenButton });` statement? 
Because in the

```
if (...) {
  //...
} else {
  this.onAnswer(this.state.value, item.id);
}
```

part value has still not updated.

I've tried creating a separate function called `stateUpdated` which houses the `setState` call, timeouts and other ways of delaying the execution to allow for the state to update, but it seems the issue is not time based but something else completely.

I am also aware that I could just use `chosenButton` in the last else statement instead of the `value` but I am more interested in understanding the "Why?" of this problem and not how to "fix" my code as such.

```
keyInput(event) {
    const moduleState = StudentModuleState;
    const item: Item = moduleState.displayedItems[0];
    const practice: boolean = !StudentModuleState.itemSet.assessment_set;

    if (!this || !this._isMounted) { return; }
    this.setState({ value: this.state.chosenButton }); 

    if (practice) {
        if (this.state.chosenButton === item.correct) {
            this.setState({ answerCorrect: true })
            setTimeout(() => this.progressHandler(), 2000);
        } else {
            this.setState({ answerWrong: true, })
            setTimeout(() => this.progressHandler(), 2000);
        }
    } else {
        this.onAnswer(this.state.value, item.id);
    }
}
```

Comment: _`setState()` does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading `this.state` right after calling `setState() `a potential pitfall. Instead, use `componentDidUpdate` or a `setState` callback (`setState(updater, callback)`), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update has been applied. If you need to set the state based on the previous state, read about the `updater` argument below._ ([ref.](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate))

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! When you say "Instead, use componentDidUpdate" how exactly would you apply it in the example code above? I've gotten to grips using things like "componentWill/DidMount" and the reverse of these but have not yet used said componentDidUpdate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm going to assume here that my problem lies within the async nature of how React states work...

That's right. The state update is asynchronous, so code immediately following the `setState` call still sees the old state. To wait until it's updated, use the update callback (the second argument to `setState`):

```
keyInput(event) {
    const moduleState = StudentModuleState;
    const item: Item = moduleState.displayedItems[0];
    const practice: boolean = !StudentModuleState.itemSet.assessment_set;

    if (!this || !this._isMounted) { return; }
    this.setState(
        { value: this.state.chosenButton },
        () => {
            if (practice) {
                if (this.state.chosenButton === item.correct) {
                    this.setState({ answerCorrect: true })
                    setTimeout(() => this.progressHandler(), 2000);
                } else {
                    this.setState({ answerWrong: true, })
                    setTimeout(() => this.progressHandler(), 2000);
                }
            } else {
                this.onAnswer(this.state.value, item.id);
            }
        }
    ); 
}
```

---

Side note about this:

```
    this.setState(
        { value: this.state.chosenButton },
        // ------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

It appears you're updating state in response to a button press (remembering which button was pressed), and then using that updated state in response to a keyboard event. That's okay only because React specifically handles it: It guarantees that the previous state change in response to a `click` will be rendered (and thus applied) before the next event is dispatched. These used to be called "interactive" events, but now are called "discrete" events, you can find a list [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react-dom/src/events/SimpleEventPlugin.js). Note that this is for `click` and various keyboard events, and **not** for things like `mousemove`. Details in [this twitter thread](https://twitter.com/tjcrowder/status/1127200387876970497), where Dan Abramov (a core committer on the React project) writes:

> Even in Concurrent Mode, we indeed guarantee React events like “click” and others that imply intentional user action will flush before the next one is handled. Your “disabled” example is one of the motivations.
>
> ---
>
> Note we don’t guarantee first click is processed synchronously. Only that if you click the next time, we’ll make sure to flush the results of the first one before we decide whether to handle the next event or ignore it.
>
> ---
>
> You can find a list of such events here. (Called “interactive” in code now although that might not be the best naming). https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react-dom/src/events/SimpleEventPlugin.js
>
> ---
>
> We don’t make such guarantees for events like “mousemove” which are continuous rather than discrete. For those we assume it’s safe to batch and sometimes skip intermediate ones as user doesn’t intentionally think about each move as a separate event.
>
> ---
>
> Also note in Concurrent Mode these guarantees only are enforced for React events. If you subscribe manually via addEventListener() there’s some extra stuff you’ll need to do to have them.
>
> However, today (in sync mode) those are always sync. So just something for the future.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Can you either elaborate further on how the async nature of the state update works on my example or are you aware of some good read/video on the subject matter so I could get a better understanding of the subject at hand? For example what is exactly happening at the point of: 
{ value: this.state.chosenButton },
        () => {..... What does the empty "()" in fact do?

Comment: @KsK - That's just the empty parameter list for the [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) I've used to define the callback. The whole `() => { /*...*/ }` is a function, which is being passed into `setState` as the second argument. React will call that function after the state update has been applied.

Comment: Ah so does this mean in essence:

- the setState gets called but since it's async it won't be executed immediately.
- the callback function ensures that whatever is inside it only gets called after the setState has been executed.

Is that the gist of it or have I missed the point?

Comment: @KsK - Yup, that's it exactly. `setState` just queues a state update, it doesn't perform it immediately. When it returns, the update hasn't been done yet. Later, when it's done, React calls the callback.